# It's better to keep one week or one day in a row of an table in SQL?

Tags: database

I'm doing a system that keep presences about the users, your know, if they are in that day or not.

I simple want to know if it would be more practical to keep data about a entire week in a table's row or only a day per row.

If it's a week per row it would have this attributes:

user : varChar
day 1 (Sunday) : dateTime 
day 2 (Monday) : dateTime 
...
day 7 (Saturday) : dateTime

If it's per day:

user : varChar
date : dateTime
presence : boolean

So? What do you think?

Comment: How do you intend to use the data?

Comment: Which date does `date` represent in the first design? Are you expecting to query on "Week starting ( / ending / including )" or "Date ="?

Comment: Basically this table will be associated with another table within the users, everyday or every week it will be launched the presences for each user.

Comment: @Caleth Oops, sorry, this doesn't make sense, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you are using MySQL, or a database with a built-in date/time type.

If you want maximum flexibility in the future (since you cannot predict how this data may be used), then make the date/time interval **generic**: store "presence entries" in the database, which indicate when a user is present.  It would have a structure like this:

table presence_entries
user_id (int) | from (MySQL Datetime) | to (MySQL DateTime)

This is good because if a user is present for many intervals per day or week, you can capture them all in your report.  In the future, if you want to change your report to bi-weekly or monthly, no problem.

Comment: One thing to add: if a user's presence time crosses the "day" boundary at midnight, this method will handle it gracefully.  Second thing to add: MySQL's built-in `<` and `>` WHERE conditions can be used to build your report, based on any date you wish.